# Add intermediate rows in a dataframe based on the previous record

Tags: python, dataframe

Be the following dataframe:

| ID | direction | country | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | IN | USA | 12:10 |
| 0 | OUT | FRA | 14:20 |
| 0 | OUT | ESP | 16:11 |
| 1 | IN | GER | 11:13 |
| 1 | OUT | USA | 10:29 |
| 2 | OUT | USA | 09:21 |
| 2 | OUT | ESP | 21:33 |

I would like to add the following functionality to the above dataframe:

If there are two rows sequentially with the value of the attribute "direction" equal to OUT for the same ID. An intermediate row is created with the same data of the first OUT row by changing the direction to IN.

Here is an example applied to the above dataframe:

| ID | direction | country | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | IN | USA | 12:10 |
| 0 | OUT | FRA | 14:20 |
| 0 | IN | FRA | 14:20 |
| 0 | OUT | ESP | 16:11 |
| 1 | IN | GER | 11:13 |
| 1 | OUT | USA | 10:29 |
| 2 | OUT | USA | 09:21 |
| 2 | IN | USA | 09:21 |
| 2 | OUT | ESP | 21:33 |

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a new dataframe

```
dfNew = pd.DataFrame()
```

and loop through each row of the existing dataframe.

```
for column_name, item in dfOld.iteritems():
```

Look at the value under `direction` with every loop, and if it is `IN`, take that entire row and append it to the new dataframe.

```
dfNew.append(item, ignore_index=True)
```

If it is `out`, add the entire row as above, but also create a new row

```
dfNew.loc[len(dfNew.index)] = [value1, value2, value3, ...]
```

or edit the existing row (contained in `item`) and add it to the new dataframe as well.